# A Proof of the Ratio test connecting it with the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Whilst studying complex analysis I met a proof connecting of the ratio test connecting it with the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem. Can someone walk me through the proof? I can't seem to understand any of the steps,  especially the first bit about the induction and the last bit deducing the result. I attempted to prove the induction part of my self but I couldn't get a term independent of a for the LHS side of the inequality.

This is something that has been bothering me for a while since I haven't been able to find a similar proof online and I have been stuck not being able to understand it.

I have attached a photo here[image: Proof provided in the book]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the photo from ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Serge Lange's Complex Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints: let us denote $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n_0-1} \frac {a_{k+1}} {a_k}$ by $D$ (dependence on $\epsilon$ is supressed). Then $a_n \leq a_1D(A+\epsilon)^{n-n_0+1}$ since  a product of $n-n_0+1$ numbers, each of which is $\leq A+\epsilon$, is $\leq (A+\epsilon)^{n-n_0+1}$. Taking $C_2(\epsilon)=a_1D(A+\epsilon)$ we have proved the right hand inequality and the left  hand inequality is similar.

The last part is straightforward if you remember that $|\delta_1(n)| \leq \frac {\epsilon} {A-\epsilon}$ and $|\delta_2(n)| \leq \frac {\epsilon} {A+\epsilon}$

Comment: Hey, all of your comments make perfect sence. I have now only one remaining problem. Do you know where the part from there exists N=> n_0 to the end of the statements about C1'(ϵ) and C2'(ϵ) come from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KanyeWest $x^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $x >0$. Hence, given $\delta >0$ there exits $n_0$ such that $x^{1/n}  <1+\delta$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Apply this with $x=C_1'(\epsilon)$ and $\delta =\epsilon /(A-\epsilon)$. Similar argument for $C_2'(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Hey, I tried that and I got the following. The first tine I did it on C’1 to get that it is < 1 + epsilon then I did it for what C’1 stands for (C’1=C1(A-epsilon)^(-n_o). I used epsilon for the first and delta for the second. I compared the two to get an expression connecting epsilon and delta but I didn’t get the desired delta<epsilon/(epsilon - etta). Is it my algebra or my method that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem (Cesaro-Stoltz). If $\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n=C$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n c_j=C.$

Let every $a_j>0$ and let $b_j=a_{j+1}/a_j.$ Then $ a_{n+1}=a_1\prod_{j=1}^nb_j,$ so $$(\bullet)\quad\frac {\log a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac {\log a_1}{n+1}+\frac {n}{n+1}\left(\frac {1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\log  b_j\right). $$

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\,a_{n+1}/a_n=A>0$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\,b_n=A >0$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\,\log b_n=\log A.$ Applying the above theorem to $(\bullet)$ with $c_n=\log b_n$, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\log (\,(a_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}\,)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\log a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\log A.$$

Remark. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1/n)\sum_{j=1}^n c_j=C$ then $C$ is (usually) called the Cesaro mean of the sequence $(c_n)_n$ regardless of whether or not  $\lim_{n\to \infty}c_n$ exists.

A variation on the theme of the above theorem is that if $c_n\to -\infty$ as $n\to -\infty$ then $(1/n)\sum_{j=1}^nc_j\to -\infty.$ So if $0=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}/a_n$ then $\log b_j\to -\infty$ so from $(\bullet)$ we obtain $\log (\,(a_{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}\,)\to -\infty.$

Comment: Hi, this is not the proof that I was looking for but this gave me another way of looking at the theorem. Thank you for your time.