# Follow Up Question for the Proof of the Ratio test connecting it with the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

About a month ago I posted here [A Proof of the Ratio test connecting it with the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236276/a-proof-of-the-ratio-test-connecting-it-with-the-cauchy-hadamard-theorem) and it was successfully answered but I don't understand one step. In particular, I have trouble understanding the bond for  C1'(epsilon).

The full proof provided from my book: [image: Extract]

My Attempt: [image]

But comparing it with the answer I get that the product^1/n must be equal to A so I doubt that I have done it correctly.

I understand the rest of proof thanks to the previous thread but only have trouble understanding the bound for delta ( that its absolute value is =< (A/(A-epsilon).

If anybody could shine light on this problem I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important fact here is that $C_1'(\epsilon)$ and $C_2'(\epsilon)$ are positive constants.

Bounding $\left(C_i'(\epsilon) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ comes from the fact:

- For any $C>0$ you have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{C} = 1$

Since it may happen that $0< C_i'(\epsilon) < 1$ for one or both them, then $\sqrt[n]{C_i'(\epsilon)}\nearrow 1$, so $\delta_i(n)$ can be negative, as well.

The choice of the bounds for $\delta_i(n)$ reveals itself if you write down the last chain of inequalities completely:

LHS:

$$A- 2\epsilon = \color{blue}{A-\epsilon - (A-\epsilon)\frac{\epsilon}{A-\epsilon}  \stackrel{|\delta_1(n)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{A-\epsilon}}{\leq}}A-\epsilon + \delta_1(n)(A-\epsilon ) \leq a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

RHS:

$$a_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq A+\epsilon + \delta_2(n)(A+\epsilon)\color{blue}{\stackrel{|\delta_2(n)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{A+\epsilon}}{\leq} A+\epsilon + (A+\epsilon)\frac{\epsilon}{A+\epsilon} } = A+2\epsilon$$

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer @trancelocation ! I was wondering if you can just clarify to things for me does 1) ↗ mean tending to? and 2) so the bond of delta is not derived but rather chosen such that to omit the desired result or am I wrong (which is a valid operation since delta is arbitrary)?

Comment: @KanyeWest 1): $\nearrow 1$ means that (if $0<C<1$) the sequence is increasing and converges to $1$. And 2): Yes, exactly. We know that for a constant $C>0$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{C}=1$. So, we can find for any given $\epsilon' > 0$ an index $N_{\epsilon'}$ such that for all $n \geq N_{\epsilon'}$ we have 
$$|\underbrace{\sqrt[n]{C}-1}_{=\delta(n)}|\leq \epsilon' \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{C} = 1+ (\sqrt[n]{C}-1) = 1+\delta(n) \mbox{ with } |\delta(n)| < \epsilon'$$

Now, you may set $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{A-\epsilon}$ or $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{A+\epsilon}$, resp.